After a divorce, what corollary relief may remain available?
After a divorce has been ordered, what corollary relief (orders for property division, spousal support, child support, etc.) may remain available to the former spouses?

united-states

After a divorce has been ordered, what corollary relief (orders for
property division, spousal support, child support, etc.) may remain
available to the former spouses?

Preliminary Orders
Prior to the entry of a divorce, preliminary orders relating to parenting time and parental responsibilities, payment of outstanding bills and expenses including legal expenses, and child and spousal support during the pendency of the divorce litigation, and use of marital property will often be entered and some form of protective order is often put in place.
Preliminary orders also often deadlines and hearing dates for the rest of the case, determine what information must be disclosed prior to a permanent orders hearing, and may order DNA paternity tests.
These orders may be modified during the course of the case if necessary.
Permanent Orders
The divorce decree itself will usually contain findings of fact establishing that all jurisdictional prerequisites to a divorce (e.g. the existence of a marriage, jurisdiction over the parties, service of process, completion of the waiting periods required under state law, etc.) have been completed and establishing jurisdiction over the children of the marriage under the pertinent state and federal statutes.
The permanent orders will generally make findings of fact concerning the finances of the couple (income, expenses, assets, and debts), the duration of their marriage, the ages and relationships of their children, any special needs of the children, and other facts relevant to the conclusions reached in permanent orders.
When there is a prenuptial agreement, it will determine if all or some of that agreement was valid and enforceable, which may affect post-decree litigation as well.
If both parties requested a legal separation, rather than a true divorce, the marriage is left intact, but the other permanent orders are entered, and a statement regarding what must be done by either spouse to convert a legal separation to a true divorce is included in the legal separation decree.
Normally, at the time a divorce is entered, sometimes called "permanent orders" a court will also enter orders for a division of property and debts, including pets, and will sometimes include the creation of a debt between ex-spouses if a suitable equitable division of property and debts cannot be secured in any other way. Orders regarding a division of defined benefit pensions, called QDROs, are sometimes entered and are often quite complicated.
It will sometimes award alimony, and there will sometimes be a statement regarding when alimony terminates and under what circumstances it can be modified.
It will sometimes order a name change if requested for one or both the spouses.
There will often be an allocation of attorneys' fees and costs for the proceeding. Sometimes, in connection with this, one or more litigation sanctions for misconduct in the litigation will be imposed at that time (e.g. attorney's fee awards for inadequate disclosures of financial information or for failure to cooperate with a deposition).
Many permanent orders provisions relate to children such as orders related to parenting time and parental responsibilities and child support, and infrequently, a name change and/or paternity adjudication for one or more children. Provisions related to parental responsibilities will sometimes include detailed guidance regarding the religious upbringing and education of and place of residence of the children, if any.
If the order contains regular payments, the order may provide details regarding the exact logistics of how this is done (e.g. through the registry of the court, or by wage assignment). Often, there will be an order for ongoing financial disclosures related to child support and a protective order operative after the divorce.
Permanent orders will often contain provisions regarding how the tax returns of the parties will be filed for the years of the divorce litigation and any years where there are unfiled and overdue taxes, and for the allocation of tax benefits related to children.
In rare instances, the court may also quiet title to, or order the partition of, marital property in which a third-party also has an interest.
Matters which can't be ordered by the divorce court
A divorce court does not generally have the jurisdiction to order a third-party creditor to refrain from attempting to collect a debt entered into by both spouses which was allocated to one spouse or the other in a divorce decree. It also can't unilaterally release a spouse from an obligation on a mortgage or car loan when the house or car in question is assigned to one spouse or the other. But, the spouse receiving the mortgaged asset can be ordered to attempt to refinance the debt or to sell the asset if it cannot be refinanced.
A divorce court does not generally have the jurisdiction to rule on the immigration status of the parties or the children. It may, however, make findings of fact concerning their citizenship, and it may direct a parent to take steps to formalize the citizenship of one or more children.
Post-Decree Orders
If the orders in a divorce are appealed and not affirmed on appeal, the case if remanded to the trial court to enter new orders consistent with the appellate court's rulings.
If a court retained jurisdiction over the case and all of the parties to the case have moved away, sometimes the court will enter a post-decree relinquishment of jurisdiction over the case.
Property and debt divisions may be modified after permanent orders (in Colorado, up to five years after permanent orders, or when otherwise necessary to quiet title) when there are newly discovered significant assets or debts.
After permanent orders, courts will often modify parenting time and parental responsibilities and child support (and, less often, will modify alimony) in response to changing circumstances.
One fairly common modification of permanent orders is to modify an order granting "reasonable parenting time to each party" because a detailed court order seemed unnecessary at the time, to make it more specific.
Sometimes the courts will handle motions to enforce permanent orders (as amended, if at all).
Sometimes after permanent orders, a court will also issue orders clarifying ambiguities in an original divorce decree or separation agreement.
In practice, it is rare in cases where the children are young at the time of the divorce for there not to be some post-decree litigation, and orders modifying or clarifying or enforcing a divorce decree are not uncommon even in cases where there are no common children.
Big Picture Analysis
Generally speaking, being married and then getting divorced provides a significant economic benefit to a spouse who has a lower income and less property relative to the rights that this spouse would have had if the spouse had been a member of an unmarried couple. This is especially true in couples with more combined wealth and income, in longer marriages, and in marriages with children (where alimony awards tend to be higher, in addition to any child support that is awarded).
But for couples with minimal or no assets, low and similar incomes, and short marriages, the expense of getting a divorce may be high relative to the benefits obtained from getting married and then divorced for either spouse, and marriage may, in hindsight, may not have been worth it to either spouse economically.
The rights of unmarried co-parents are essentially the same, with regard to parenting time, parental responsibilities, and child support, and attorneys' fees and costs incurred in connection with disputes over those issues, and with respect to any name changes for their children, as it would be if they were married.
Court orders in family law matters aren't always enforced and obeyed perfectly, but post-decree enforcement of these court orders is far from impotent either.

This will depend on the jurisdiction.
british-columbia
But for example, in British Columbia,

A spouse may start a proceeding for an order under Part 5 [Property Division] to divide property or family debt, Part 6 [Pension Division] to divide a pension, or Part 7 [Child and Spousal Support] for spousal support, no later than 2 years after,
(a) in the case of spouses who were married, the date
(i) a judgment granting a divorce of the spouses is made ...

An application for child support can be started at any time.
It is not rare that separation or divorce happens prior to seeking an order for property division, support, or other corollary relief.
ontario
In Ontario, such applications can also be made within two years of divorce.
